# How can I turn off click/touch to drag controls in A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm using a-frame and I would like to turn off the default looking around behaviour of the mouse or finger when you click and drag to look around. I want to take control of scrolling and move around the 3D space when the user scrolls instead. How can I stop that default behaviour?

So far I have this:

```
 <a-camera position="0 5 8" fov="50" touchEnabled="false" wasd-controls-enabled="false" look-controls="false" touchEnabled="false">
```

But none of these attributes makes any difference to that default behaviour.

I do still need click/tapping on objects to work with the raycaster so turning off EVERYTHING mouse/touch related would be no good, I just want to turn off click/touch to drag and look around.

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a-entity camera></a-entity>`

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/chestnut-brook-cheddar?path=index.html%3A12%3A0

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `look-controls="false"` attribute with `look-controls-enabled="false"`

```
<a-camera position="0 5 8" fov="50" touchEnabled="false" wasd-controls-enabled="false" look-controls-enabled="false" touchEnabled="false">
```